# Highlight numeric characters in a maskedtextbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, richtextbox, usability, maskedtextbox

I am using a masked text box to allow users to enter a serial number. The problem is that this serial number has to be communicated over the phone and people seem to be having trouble differentiating between O and 0 and I and 1.

I thought that a good solution to this might be some way of highlighting which characters in the textbox were numeric characters (as opposed to alphabetic characters). Obviously there is no way to do this without using a richtextbox and then I lose the masking ability.

Can anyone think of a good solution to this? (Changing the font to one that has a slashed 0 would help but not for I and 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for a font with a slashed zero and a 1 with serifs. To stop confusing the I with 1, you could use lower case letters to have a dotted i.
Better even... avoid 1,0,I and O in your serial numbers...?

Comment: Hindsight is always 20-20 but now we have serial numbers out there which contain 0, 1, O and I - we can't change that now.

Comment: I am going to use a slashed zero font to help with this but have also added a tooltip to the text box which shows the phonetic representation of the string e.g. Alpha Zero Golf One - Juliet, Mike Zero Two etc. These two things should help in 99% of cases